# How to solve deep object requests with RXJS

Tags: angular, promise, rxjs

I need to request an endpoint and from this endpoint, need to create / request a next endpoint, but this need to be completed all at the same time, like that, when I subscribe to receive the results, all nexted "Promises" needs be is already solved.

```
import { forkJoin } from 'rxjs';
import { map, mergeMap, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { fromFetch } from 'rxjs/fetch';

// https://api.github.com/users?per_page=5 -- **Used just to explain**
fromFetch('https://api.github.com/users?per_page=5').pipe(
  switchMap(res => res.json()),
  mergeMap(item => item),
  map((item: any) => {
    item.my_object_base = {
      // This result need be "completed" join with the current request
      next_item: fromFetch(item.repos_url).pipe(
        switchMap(res => res.json()),
      )
    }
    return item;
  }),
  // which pipe should i run to solve the nexted Observable?
).subscribe((res) => {
  console.log(res)
  /**
     {
         ...
         my_object_base : {
             next_item: Observable // This still is a observable
         }
         ...
     }
  **/
})
```

How to solve this question? I'm open to opions and another correct way to solve the problem

Comment: I'm not sure why this has been down voted ... but it would help if you could do a stackblitz with an example illustrating your issue. In general, using something like `combineLatest` will ensure that each of the Observables emit before continuing. If that is what you are asking, I can provide an example.

Comment: Yea, I think its confusing about what you are exactly trying to do. This code alone doesn't tell us how many pages of users you are trying to retrieve or give us a clear idea of what data you are wanting. Provide a real example that either attempts to work, or works but doesn't return the right results and you'll get feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Update: I simplified the logic a little and should do what I "think" you were trying to accomplish.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qr86ry

```
this.http
  .get("https://api.github.com/users?per_page=5")
  .pipe(
    switchMap((response: []) => {
      return from(response);
    }),
    concatMap((response: any) => {
      return this.http.get(response.repos_url).pipe(map((x) => {
        response.my_object_base = x;
        return response;
      }));
    })
  )
  .subscribe(res => {
    console.log(res);
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
this.user$ = this.http.get<GithubUser>('https://api.github.com/users/mojombo');

this.hisFirstRepoName$ = this.user$.pipe(
  switchMap(user => this.http.get(user.repos_url).pipe(map(repos => repos[0].name))),
);

this.data$ = combineLatest([this.user$, this.hisFirstRepoName$]).pipe(
  map(([user,hisFirstRepoName]) => `${user.login}:${hisFirstRepoName}`),
);
```

Working Demo:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ajyxbq

Comment: Ok, this also works like I need. Thanks...There were 2 examples of how I can solve this. @damian-c